# ABAS edpimport how to update Employee Bank Details

Tags: erp, abas

What is the right way to update employee bank details ( database 96:02 ) using the edpimport.sh.

The difficulty that I am facing is that I want to use the employee ID as the key attribute to reference the required change in ABAS , not the bank details ID( num96 ).

Comment: Please clarify how this is [programming related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If this question is about how to *use* ABAS, [super user](http://superuser.com) might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. I usually build a loop in my FOP with a select statement to get the id's i need and then build the edpimport.sh script to run

```
#!ACTION=UPDATE
#!DATABASE=96
#!GROUP=2

id;field1
(1,2,3);somethinghere
```

The follow example from the help to use selection statements inside your script manual might work, but I haven't done anything like it.

```
#!ACTION=STORE
#!DATABASE=20
#!GROUP=1
#!LINESEPARATOR=#
#!FLDDELIMITER=|
#!CHARSET=ISO8859

recordid|such|name|yfeld1|yfeld2\
rowid|ytfeld1|ytfeld2
$,,name=BMW  323;yfeld2=München|BMW|BMW  323|BMW  Werke|München\
$,,tfeld2=M-MW  323|ja|M-MW  323\
$,,tfeld2=M-MW  324|ja|M-MW  324
$,,name=Ford  Fiesta;yfeld2=Köln|FORD|Ford  Fiesta|Ford  Werke|Köln\
$,,tfeld2=K-FF  99|ja|K-FF  99\
$,,tfeld2=K-FF  98|nein|K-FF  98\
$,,tfeld2=K-FF-97|ja|K-FF  97
$,,name=Opel  Astra;yfeld2=Eisenach|OPEL|Opel  Astra|Opel  Werk|Eisenach\
$,,tfeld2=GG-OA  123|ja|GG-OA  123\
$,,tfeld2=GG-OA  123|ja|GG-OA  234\
$,,tfeld2=GG-OA  345|nein|GG-OA  345
$,,name=VW  Golf;yfeld2=Wolfsburg|VW|VW  Golf  IV|Volkswagen  Werk|Wolfsburg\
$,,tfeld2=WOB-G  999|ja|WOB-G  999
...
```